# Get attribute's name by it's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to return the key with a known `value` from my model.

```
f = Foo.find_by(name: "dave")
#= returned object: {id: 1, name: "dave", age: 32}
f.key("dave") # expected :name or name
```

This `value` will be unique. How to get the attribute? Am I asking the right question?

What is the difference with this, please?

```
hash = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300, "d" => 300 }
hash.key(200) #=> "b"
```

Comment: What you are asking is given the value you how do you return the name of that `key` from an `activerecord` record with that value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f` is an instance of `Foo` class, which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, it is not a `Hash` instance.

To get the attribute's name by it's value (using `key`), you have to get a hash of `f`'s [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#`attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) first:

```
f.attributes.key('dave') # `attributes` method returns a Hash instance
#=> "name"
```

> What is the difference

To sum up: the difference in the instance methods defined in the object's class.

Comment: Wow! I never knew that. Im still learning. So `f.attributes` is the hash? Ok.

Comment: Didn't know you could do this.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed and had no clue is possible! Awesome!